# xenserver-iso: Error downloading: open : no such file or directory

Tags: xen, packer

I'm trying to build a "vdi_vhd" image using packer on xenserver,but i have got the below error, could you please anyone help me on this,Thanks in advance.

```
   [root@localhost bin]# packer build /usr/local/test-scripts/main.json
 xenserver-iso output will be in this color.

 ==> xenserver-iso: XAPI client session established
 ==> xenserver-iso: Downloading or copying ISO
     xenserver-iso: Downloading or copying: http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/mirror.centos.org/7.6.1810/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1810.iso
     xenserver-iso: Error downloading: open : no such file or directory
 ==> xenserver-iso: ISO download failed. Build 'xenserver-iso' errored: ISO download failed.

 ==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
 --> xenserver-iso: ISO download failed.

 ==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

[image]

These are the steps i used to install packer

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/packer/
cd /usr/local/packer/
wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/packer/1.4.1/packer_1.4.1_linux_amd64.zip
unzip packer_1.4.1_linux_amd64.zip
vim ~/.bashrc
##added the below
export PATH=/usr/local/packer/:$PATH
##save and exit
sudo ln -s /usr/local/packer/packer /usr/bin/packer
source ~/.bashrc
```

These are the steps i used to install xenserver-iso plugin

```
RELEASE="go1.12.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz";
cd /tmp && curl -L -O "https://dl.google.com/go/${RELEASE}";
tar -zxvf "${RELEASE}";
mv -v go $HOME/go-1.12.6;
rm -f "/tmp/${RELEASE}";
vim ~/.bashrc
##added the below
export GOROOT=$HOME/go-1.12.6;
export GOPATH=$HOME/go-workspace;
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin;
##save and exit

source ~/.bashrc
mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/hashicorp/packer;
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hashicorp/packer;
go get github.com/mitchellh/gox;
go get github.com/mitchellh/go-vnc;
cd $GOPATH;
PROV="src/github.com/xenserver";
mkdir -p $PROV && cd $PROV;
git clone https://github.com/xenserver/packer-builder-xenserver.git;
cd packer-builder-xenserver;
./build.sh;
```

### verify plugin

```
[root@localhost bin]# ll
total 34732
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 17813736 Jul  2 12:04 packer-builder-xenserver-iso
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 17747856 Jul  2 12:04 packer-builder-xenserver-xva
[root@localhost bin]# pwd
/root/go-workspace/src/github.com/xenserver/packer-builder-xenserver/bin
[root@localhost bin]#
```

NOTE: I've installed packer and xenserver plugin on my Virtual-box local server

```
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "iso_checksum": "38d5d51d9d100fd73df031ffd6bd8b1297ce24660dc8c13a3b8b4534a4bd291c",
      "iso_checksum_type": "sha256",
      "iso_url": "{{user `mirror`}}/7.6.1810/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1810.iso",
      "output_directory": "CentOS-7-x86_64-xenserver-minimal",
      "format": "vdi_vhd",
      "remote_host": "192.1XX.XX.XX",
      "remote_password": "XXXXX",
      "remote_username": "root",
      "shutdown_command": "/sbin/halt",
      "ssh_password": "XXXXX",
      "ssh_username": "root",
      "ssh_wait_timeout": "10000s",
      "type": "xenserver-iso",
      "vm_name": "packer-centos-7.6-x86_64"
    }
  ],
  "variables": {
    "mirror": "http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/mirror.centos.org"
  }
}
```

I expect the output something like the below,

```
==> Builds finished. The artifacts of successful builds are
```

Answer (score 0):

your ISO link is incorrect. find another link, manually test it first then run the packer again. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkbVU.png)

Comment: What is the purpose of that image?

Comment: It shows that the ISO link is obsolete/incorrect.